Отображение выбранной культуры в национальном языке
Стоит задача сохранить в свойстве культуры её название не только на английском языке но и на родном. Каким способом можно это реализовать?
Вот пример моего кода:
private void ButtonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SelectedCulture = new CultureInfo(TextBoxInput.Text);
        TextBoxEnglishName.Text = SelectedCulture.EnglishName;
        TextBoxNationalName.Text = SelectedCulture.DisplayName;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        SelectedCulture = null;
        TextBoxEnglishName.Text = "";
        TextBoxNationalName.Text = "";

        MessageBox.Show("Undefined culture!");
    }
}

А это результат:


Вероятно тут нужен .NativeName

@Grundy спасибо. То что нужно.
